# How to add a class on selected tr only not on all tr? I'm new to Angular

Tags: angular

[enter image description here][1] Here is the code . on I click its add class to `tr`. But its add open-list class to all tr element but I want to add only to the selected item. Here you can see the what's the structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/alkXy.jpg

```
<tr *ngFor="let patient of mf.data let i = index" role="row" class="odd" [ngClass]="status ? 'open-list' : 'close-list'">
  <td class="sorting_1 p-name list-icon p-name" tabindex="0">
    <i (click)="status=!status" class="fas fa-angle-right arrow-right"></i>
    <a [routerLink]="['/app/patients/patient-detail/'+patient._id]">
      {{patient.first_name}} {{patient.last_name}}
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have 4 TS Files..

Add patient ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'cat-page',
  templateUrl: './add-patient.html'
})

export class AddPatientPage implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

2.Patient Detail

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'cat-page',
  templateUrl: './patient-detail.html'
})

export class PatientDetail implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

3.Patient Module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AuthGuard } from '../../services/auth.guard';
import {TranslateModule} from "ng2-translate";
import {DataTableModule} from "angular2-datatable";

import { NgUploaderModule } from 'ngx-uploader'

import { SharedModule }   from '../../shared/shared.module'; 
import { Ng2AutoCompleteModule } from 'ng2-auto-complete';
//pages
import { PatientsPage } from './patients.page';
import { AddPatientPage } from './add-patient.page';
import { PatientDetail } from './patient-detail.page';

//components
import { PatientListComponent } from '../../components/patients/patient-list.component';
import { PatientAddFormComponent } from '../../components/patients/patient-addform.component';
import { PatientDetailComponent } from '../../components/patients/patient-detail.component';
// import { PatientDetailContentComponent } from '../../components/patients/patient-detail-content.component';
import { PatientInvoiceListComponent } from '../../components/patients/patient-invoice-list.component';
import { PatientPaymentListComponent } from '../../components/patients/patient-payment-list.component';
import { PatientAttachmentComponent } from '../../components/patients/patient-attachment-list.component';



export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PatientsPage, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'add', component: AddPatientPage, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'add/:id', component: AddPatientPage, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'patient-detail/:id', component: PatientDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule,
    DataTableModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule,
    NgUploaderModule,
    Ng2AutoCompleteModule 
  ],
  declarations: [
    PatientsPage,
    AddPatientPage,
    PatientDetail,
    PatientListComponent,
    PatientAddFormComponent,
    PatientDetailComponent,
    PatientInvoiceListComponent,
    PatientPaymentListComponent,
    PatientAttachmentComponent
  ],
  /*exports: [
    RouterModule,
    PatientsPage,
    AddPatientPage,
    PatientDetail,
    PatientListComponent,
    PatientAddFormComponent,
    PatientDetailComponent
  ],*/
  bootstrap: [ PatientListComponent,PatientAddFormComponent ]

})

export class PatientsModule { 


}
```

4.Patient Page

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
declare var jQuery: any;

var $ = require('jquery');

@Component({
  selector: 'cat-page',
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: './patients.html'
})

export class PatientsPage {

}
```

Comment: I need to see tr opening tag

Comment: how do you know which tr is selected? this sounds like want to achieve that on click after the page has loaded or something which should be done with jquery then?

Comment: Actually, tr repeats when page loads with different amount of patient list.
Every tr has a i tag which has an icon. So when user click on icon list expands

Answer (score 0):

**TS**

```
// update array with one more field `isOpen` and use it in HTML for applying `class`

mf.data.map((obj) => {
    obj.isOpen = false;
    return obj;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr  *ngFor="let patient of mf.data let i = index" role="row" class="odd" [ngClass]="patient.isOpen ? 'open-list' : 'close-list'">
    <td class="sorting_1 p-name list-icon p-name" tabindex="0">
    <i (click)="patient.isOpen=!patient.isOpen" class="fas fa-angle-right arrow-right"></i>
        <a [routerLink]="['/app/patients/patient-detail/'+patient._id]">
            {{patient.first_name}} {{patient.last_name}}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

on `click` function `toggle` value of `isOpen`

Comment: TS through an error.. statement expected!! don't know whats wrong I'm doing

Comment: you should use above code within a method where you are updating `mf.data` .

Comment: Haven't tried yet.. will let you know soon. Is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: I'm Using Full Calendar Scheduler Plugin and I don't know where mf.data code exists. Will you help me find this?

Comment: @RoshanKumar you must be preparing `data` somewhere. can you update your question with `ts` code?

Comment: Updated with TS Code

Comment: @RoshanKumar it's not clear from your code where are you assigning data in mf.data. Where are you assigning data i.e. first_name, last_name & patient_id. If it's response from service, you can use my code to update fields in data.